# TimePicker in Wpf Toolkit

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpftoolkit, timepicker

I want a timepicker control in WPF. I found an implementation here.(http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=TimePicker&referringTitle=Home). I have installed it. But couldn't understand how to use it. I don't know what I need to write in the XAML file.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Instructions are provided in the link itself [here](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/documentation). Follow these steps and you are good to go -

1. Install the binaries first from [here](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/releases/view/96972).
2. Extract the dll `Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit` and add reference to this dll in your project.
3. In `XAML` add the namespace - `xmlns:xctk="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit"`

4.Then add the instance of `TimePickerControl` in your xaml -

```
<Grid>
   <xctk:TimePicker Height="30" Width="100" Value="{Binding CurrentDateTime}"/>
</Grid>
```

In your ViewModel -

```
private DateTime currentDateTime = DateTime.Now;
public DateTime CurrentDateTime
{
   get
   {
      return currentDateTime ;
   }
   set
   {
      currentDateTime = value;
   }
}
```

Comment: `Binding` works in the same way as for other controls. See the updated answer to bind dateTime for TimePickerControl.

Comment: I Got this Error when I add time picker to xaml The name "TimePicker" does not exist in the namespace "http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit".

Comment: @janakaaravinda, The best way I found to get that error fixed was to use nuget to upload. Try this page https://www.nuget.org/packages/Extended.Wpf.Toolkit.Plus/3.0.16174.17450 and this one https://docs.nuget.org/consume/package-manager-console